# Table naming convention for configuring a jdbcRealm in GlassFish

Tags: java, naming-conventions, glassfish, glassfish-3, jdbcrealm

I am trying to configure a jdbcRealm in GlassFishV3 using existing tables that have a naming convention other than "users" and "groups"; the realm does not appear to work unless the tables are named this way. My question is, why the limitation? Is there a work around other than renaming my existing tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to rename your tables or at least join to these. JDBC Realm, Tomcat's as well as GlassFish's require certain schema constraints as you point out.

There is hope, I guess there are enough people that do not like these limitations that there is an alternate implementation here: http://flexiblejdbcrealm.wamblee.org/

I have not tried it, looks like it will do what you want.

Comment: Indeed the FlexibleJdbcRealm is what I am looking for; however I have not been able to get the realm working using the installation guide. I may just go the other route and join to a "users" and "groups" table. Thanks.